# How to debug only written code in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-code

I am developing with angular using vscode.

In this case, the tool debugging step through all the source code include low code from the breakpoint state,

Is there a way to jump to own code?

Is there a way to step into only my code?

(I want to jump to the own code using F10, without next breakpoint (From the breakpoint state)

Comment: Set breakpoints?

Comment: Use f10 and f11 properly (?!?!?!?)

Comment: I want to jump to the own code using f10, without next breakpoint (From the breakpoint state)

Comment: Just put a breakpoint (or `debugger;`) at some lines and the use f10 to move down. If you want to enter a function instead of f10 use f11 and the, when you are inside the function, continue with f10, and so on